# SharePoint -integrating CKEditor

Tags: sharepoint

I am needing to replace the default HTML editor that comes with WSS 3.0 by CKEditor to edit web parts.

I read about adding a new content type but I am working on a limited shared host.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you able to install your own custom solutions (WSP files)?

Comment: Hi Tim -thank you for your help. I just answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI -it seems you need access to the 12 hive folder to integrate CKEditor with WSS 3.0. Because we are running our site on shared hosting, we do not have access to this folder. So we decided to switch to SharePoint Foundation 2010 (WSS 4.0), which comes with a complete HTML editor (e.g. image uploading, CSS styles, etc.) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 4 months old, but for anyone looking for an answer, here it is: [CKEditor for SharePoint](http://ckeditor.com/sharepoint)

Easy to install and upgrade, compatible with SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010. CKFinder is included.

Fully functional 30 days trial version is available.